streamable.com iframe api stopped emitting events
I used to support streamable.com in my library project. However all of a sudden the API stopped emitting events (playing, paused, volumechange, ...). I created a minimal html which demonstrates the issue, can't create a stackblitz because streamable blocks nested embedding.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.embed.ly/player-0.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let ready = false;
            document.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!ready) {
                    ready = true;
                    const frame = document.querySelector("#streamableFrame");
                    const player = new playerjs.Player(frame);
                    
                    player.on('play', function () { console.log('playing'); });
                    player.on('pause', function () { console.log('paused'); });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://streamable.com/o/moo" id="streamableFrame" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media; autoplay; fullscreen;" width="450" height="300" style="max-width: 100%"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>

I do get a console error

WebSocket connection to 'wss://socket.streamable.com/' failed:

Has something changed in the Streamable iframe API? Does anyone know how I can fix this?
EDIT:
Strangely, it seems that Kaltura (demo / source), which also uses player.js, still works fine. So there must be problems with Streamable.com
